# Where is the error in this solution of $\frac{dx}{y} = \frac{dy}{x} = \frac{dz}{z}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

The problem is the linear simultaneous system $$\frac{dx}{y} = \frac{dy}{x} = \frac{dz}{z}$$

From the first equation, we have

$$ \dfrac{dx}{y} = \dfrac{dy}{x} \implies xdx - ydy = 0 \implies d\left(\frac{x^2 - y^2}{2}\right) = 0 \implies  x^2 - y^2 = c_1 $$

And from this, we get $$x = \pm \sqrt{c_1 + y^2} \tag{i}$$

Therefore, from the initial equations and using (i),

$$\dfrac{dy}{x} = \dfrac{dz}{z} \implies \dfrac{dy}{\pm\sqrt{c_1 + y^2}} = \dfrac{dz}{z} \implies \pm\ln|\sqrt{c_1 + y^2} + y| = \ln|z + c_2|$$
Thus,

$$z = \pm\sqrt{c_1 + y^2} + y + c_2$$

However, the book's answer is 
$$ x^2 - y^2 = c_1, \qquad x+y = c_2 \cdot z$$

I have retraced my steps and I can't see any illegal steps, so to speak. Where did I miss it?

Comment: That shouldn't be $\text{ln}|z+c_2|$ but $\text{ln}z + c'_2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$z = \pm\sqrt{c_1 + y^2} + y + c_2$$
It should be:
$$c_2z = \pm\sqrt{c_1 + y^2} + y $$
Then:
$$c_2z =x + y $$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Your error is the expression $\ln|z+c_2|$. It should be $\ln|z|+c_2$, instead.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is at the end :
$$\dfrac{dy}{\pm\sqrt{c_1 + y^2}} = \dfrac{dz}{z}\qquad \text{OK.}$$

$$\pm\ln|\sqrt{c_1 + y^2} + y| = \ln|z|+\text{constant, but not }\ln|z+c_2|$$
Thus,

$$\pm\sqrt{c_1 + y^2} + y = c_2\:z$$

Answer (score 1):

You exploited fine $\quad x\mathop{dx}=y\mathop{dy}\quad$ to get $\quad x^2=y^2+c_1$

But you can also add these two lines $\begin{cases}x\mathop{dz}=z\mathop{dy}\\y\mathop{dz}=z\mathop{dx}\end{cases}\quad$ to get $\quad\dfrac{dz}{z}=\dfrac{d(x+y)}{x+y}$

And $\ x+y=c_2z\ $ directly.